# SQL Server database has 2 log files and I want to remove one. HOW?

Tags: sql-server, logfile

I am new to this. I have a database (created by someone else) that has 2 .ldf files. (blah_log.ldf and blah_log2.ldf). My manager asked me to remove one of the log files but I cannot. How do I do this? I tried to put it on another server, detach, delete log files, attach, but it gives an error. I thought that way it would create just one, but it wanted both. Then i tried to right click properties and delete the files, would not let me delete. It said the log file was not empty. How in the heck do I achieve this. I just want to make it where the dang database has one freaking log file not two. This shouldn't be this complicated. I am a beginner and know nothing so maybe it isn't really. Please HELP!

I just tried this:
empty SQL Server database transaction log file

backup log [dbname] with truncate_only
go
DBCC SHRINKDATABASE ([dbname], 10, TRUNCATEONLY)
go

Then I deleted the second log file and clicked ok. I guess this is all I need to do? I tried it on a test server from a restore.

Answer (score 5):

[This MSDN article describes how to accomplish this at a high-level](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191433%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

> You cannot move transaction log data from one log file to another to
>   empty a transaction log file. To remove inactive transactions from a
>   transaction log file, the transaction log must be truncated or backed
>   up. When the transaction log file no longer contains any active or
>   inactive transactions, the log file can be removed from the database.

[And this blog post shows the actual T-SQL that will accomplish this task](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/tibor_karaszi/archive/2009/06/17/remove-transaction-log-files.aspx):

```
USE master 
IF DB_ID('rDb') IS NOT NULL DROP DATABASE rDb 
GO 

CREATE DATABASE rDb 
ON  
PRIMARY  
 ( NAME = N'rDb', FILENAME = N'C:\rDb.mdf' , SIZE = 50MB , 
     FILEGROWTH = 1024KB ) 
LOG ON  
 (NAME = N'rDb_log2', FILENAME = N'C:\rDb_log2.ldf', SIZE = 3MB, 
     FILEGROWTH = 2MB) 
,(NAME = N'rDb_log3', FILENAME = N'C:\rDb_log3.ldf', SIZE = 3MB, 
     FILEGROWTH = 2MB) 
,(NAME = N'rDb_log4', FILENAME = N'C:\rDb_log4.ldf', SIZE = 3MB, 
     FILEGROWTH = 2MB) 
GO 

ALTER DATABASE rDb SET RECOVERY FULL 
BACKUP DATABASE rDb TO DISK = 'C:\rDb.bak' WITH INIT 
CREATE TABLE rDb..t(c1 INT IDENTITY, c2 CHAR(100)) 

INSERT INTO rDb..t 
SELECT TOP(15000) 'hello' 
FROM syscolumns AS a 
  CROSS JOIN syscolumns AS b 

--Log is now about 46% full 
DBCC SQLPERF(logspace) 

--Check virtual log file layout 
DBCC LOGINFO(rDb) 
--See that file 4 isn't used at all (Status = 0 for all 4's rows) 

--We can remove file 4, it isn't used 
ALTER DATABASE rDb REMOVE FILE rDb_log4 

--Check virtual log file layout 
DBCC LOGINFO(rDb) 

--Can't remove 3 since it is in use 
ALTER DATABASE rDb REMOVE FILE rDb_log3 

--What if we backup log? 
BACKUP LOG rDb TO DISK = 'C:\rDb.bak' 

--Check virtual log file layout 
DBCC LOGINFO(rDb) 
--3 is still in use (status = 2) 

--Can't remove 3 since it is in use 
ALTER DATABASE rDb REMOVE FILE rDb_log3 

--Shrink 3 
USE rDb 
DBCC SHRINKFILE(rDb_log3) 
USE master 

--... and backup log? 
BACKUP LOG rDb TO DISK = 'C:\rDb.bak' 

--Check virtual log file layout 
DBCC LOGINFO(rDb) 
--3 is no longer in use 

--Can now remove 3 since it is not in use 
ALTER DATABASE rDb REMOVE FILE rDb_log3 

--Check explorer, we're down to 1 log file 

--See what sys.database_files say? 
SELECT * FROM rDb.sys.database_files 
--Seems physical file is gone, but SQL Server consider the file offline 

--Backup log does it: 
BACKUP LOG rDb TO DISK = 'C:\rDb.bak' 
SELECT * FROM rDb.sys.database_files 

--Can never remove the first ("primary") log file 
ALTER DATABASE rDb REMOVE FILE rDb_log2 
--Note error message from above
```

Comment: One more question, in the above t0sql code I assume I change the rDB to the name of my own database. I know ... just makin' sure.

Comment: @Catahoula I'd suggest reading the linked blog post... the code is an example of how this is done, but a lot of this code is a setup / demonstration... there's only 2 - 3 commands there that you would actually run in your environment.